# Golang - How to execute function at specific times

Tags: time, go

I'm need to run a function at specific times of the day (e.g. 0010, 0610, 1210, 1810). My current approach uses a ticker `for _ = range time.Tick(21600 * time.Second)` and I manually launch the program at one of these intervals (e.g 1210). This is obviously sub-optimal.

What's the best solution to this? I thought of running the ticker every 60 seconds and then checking to see if the time matched one of the intervals, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: why not use a cron job to launch (and terminate if necessary) the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're really after here is a scheduler, so your options are:

- Limit your program to just what you want done at each interval, but use an existing scheduler to do the scheduling - a simple example would be to use a cron job (or for Windows, Task Scheduler) to launch your program according to the required schedule
- Turn your program into a scheduler in its own right, which invokes the required function correctly on schedule. Your program would then ideally need to run as a daemon (service, on Windows), or be launched once and left running all the time somehow

Comment: I removed the tick function and now use crontab commands to run the compiled executable at specific intervals. This makes the program simpler and should increase reliability.