# How do I execute commands many many times per second in Golang?

Tags: go

I want to print `N` lines per second.

```golang
for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
  fmt.Println(getLogs())
  time.Sleep(1000000000/N * time.Nanosecond)
}
```

But it seems `fmt.Println()` and `getLogs()` will also consume time. So actually it will cost me more than 1s to print `N` lines.

Say `getLogs()` and `fmt.Println()` will both cost 1 ms. And I want to print 1 million lines per second. Therefore, to print 1 line will cost 1 ms to `getLogs()`, 1 ms to print, and 1 ms to sleep... It will cost me 3s to print N lines.

Any better solutions to achieve this more accurately?

Comment: [time.NewTicker()](https://godoc.org/time#NewTicker) perhaps? i dont really get your objective. as written, as N increases, the sleep time DECREASES

Comment: @Plato ticker works if a ticker counts time in parallel to fmt.Println and getLogs,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `time.NewTicker` (try [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k69YHb5Nkn)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const N = 4
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1000000000 / N * time.Nanosecond)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        fmt.Println(getLogs(i))
        <-ticker.C
    }
    ticker.Stop()
}

func getLogs(i int) int {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    return i
}
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

---

See `func NewTicker(d Duration) *Ticker` Docs:

> `NewTicker` returns a new `Ticker` containing a channel that will send the
>   time with a period specified by the duration argument. It adjusts the
>   intervals or drops ticks to make up for slow receivers. The duration d
>   must be greater than zero; if not, `NewTicker` will panic. Stop the
>   ticker to release associated resources.

---

Also see: [Running code at noon in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386762/running-code-at-noon-golang)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.Ticker` something like

```
for range time.Tick(time.Duration(1000000000/N) * time.Nanosecond){
    fmt.Println(getLogs())
    if cond {
        break
    }
}
```